# How to run express and angular in parallel with nx?

Tags: node.js, angular, nrwl-nx

I'm new to nx and I want to create node express application with angular application.

So I ran those commands:

```
 npx create-nx-workspace // empty, nx. myorg-repo
 cd myorg-repo
 npm install --save-dev @nrwl/angular
 npm install --save-dev @nrwl/express

 nx g @nrwl/express:app express-app
 nx g @nrwl/angular:app ng-app
```

Now when I run `npm run start` or `npm run build` it only run one project.

My question is how to run `start (serve)` command in parallel with nx?

Comment: You can use an additional terminal in the  same directory. If you're using VS Code as your editor you can split the terminal window.

Comment: I looking to do it by the nx way

Comment: Regardless of the CLI used to run the project, multiple terminal windows will help. If you're really looking to run them together from a one liner... `nx serve ng-app && nx serve express-app`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
nx run-many --parallel --target=serve --projects=project1,project2,project3
```

More info on running commands in parallel with nx => https://nx.dev/previous/angular/cli/run-many

Answer (score 0):

You can also open two separate terminals or as many as you want and can start one project from each.

> terminal 1
> `nx serve ng-app`
> terminal 2
> `nx serve express-app`

Boom your servers will get started on two ports and as the proxy is already configured by nx CLI while creating a new project you just have to call your API like
`/API/20percentDone`